# c multiple fork and pipe

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I'm having problems with my code for my course I have to run different functions in different processes then pipe the results back to the parent and display it. I was having problems so I'm currently trying to understand by doing it in a basic program, but I'm still getting errors.

First i couldnt get `pid = wait(&status);` it kept saying pid was undefined then when I got around that I moved onto piping but the information doesnt seem to reach the parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PROCS 5

int main(void){
    int pipes[PROCS][2];
    pid_t ret[PROCS];
    int status = 0;
    int i;
    char msg[PROCS][100];

    for(i = 0;i < PROCS; i++){

    //create pipes
        //create pipes
        if (pipe(pipes[i]) != 0) { // Create a new pipe.
            printf("Could not create new pipe %d", i);
            exit(1);
        }

        if ((ret[i] = fork()) == -1) { 
            printf("Could not fork() new process %d\n", i);
            exit(1);
        }else if (ret[i] == 0) {//if child
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            char string[] = "child process"; //%d - process id = %d\n", i, getpid();
            write(pipes[i][0], string, 25);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    if(getpid() > 0){
        for(i = 0; i < PROCS; i++) {
            wait(&status);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < PROCS; i++) {
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            read(pipes[i][0], &msg[i], 100);
            close(pipes[i][0]);         
        }
        printf("test 1 : %s\n", msg[0]);
        printf("test 2 : %s\n", msg[1]);
        printf("test 3 : %s\n", msg[2]);
        printf("parent process - process id = %d\n", getpid());     
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    }else if (ret[i] == 0) {//if child
        close(pipes[i][1]);  <== (1)
        char string[] = "child process"; //%d - process id = %d\n", i, getpid();
        write(pipes[i][0], string, 25);  <== (2)
        exit(0);

    //.....

    for(i = 0; i < PROCS; i++) {
        close(pipes[i][1]);
        read(pipes[i][0], &msg[i], 100); <-- (3)
        close(pipes[i][0]);         
    }
```

By convention the [0] pipe element is for reading and the [1] element for writing.  You are writing [0] and then reading [0] in the parent.  Fix this and you are good to go.

```
if(getpid() > 0){
```

The above is pointless.  `getpid()` is *always* going to be greater than 0 because every process has a pid greater than zero.  You want to do this test on the pid returned from `fork` that you are storing in ret[i].  That's unnecessary in this case too because your children exit so only the parent will reach this code anyway.

*Always, always, always* check your return codes.  If you had you would have seen straight away that your pipe writes were failing and your pipe reads returning 0.

Comment: thx worked perfectly and thx for pointing out the getpid error i hadnt realised that